# MongoDB communication issues on Azure

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, python

I have a Python uWSGI app running behind Nginx using pymongo to communicate with a 4 machine replica set running [Mongodb 2.6.3](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

The replica set is configured using domain names for each machine `mdb-0[1-4].domain.com`.

I have set up MMS Monitoring to monitor the replica set and I am getting the following errors from it:

```
[2014/07/25 16:56:39] [monitoring.handler.logs-mdb-0[1-4].domain.com:27017.error] [monitoring-agent/components/bus.go:486] Failure dialing `mdb-0[1-4].domain.com:27017` for log handler. Trying again after 8s.
Failure on MongoDB dial to `mdb-0[1-4].domain.com:27017`. Err: `no reachable servers`
    at monitoring-agent/components/conf.go:138
    at monitoring-agent/components/bus.go:282
    at monitoring-agent/components/bus.go:315
    at monitoring-agent/components/bus.go:484
    at pkg/runtime/proc.c:1394
```

And:

```
[2014/07/25 17:09:43] [monitoring.process-mdb-gen-0[1-4].domain.com:27017.warn] [monitoring-agent/components/bus.go:178] Host `mdb-gen-0[1-4].domain.com:27017` slow to respond. Skipping `mongoBlocking` stats to prevent delays to other Hosts.
```

Besides this I am getting connections and BSON size errors from the Python app. Each thing is on it's own VM, they are not in a VPN and the ports are set up correctly. I am able to connect to each replica set machine using the `mongo` command line client from each of the other VMs and my own local machine.

This is the config file for each of the replica set members:

```
# mongod.conf

systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true

storage:
    journal:
        enabled: true
    dbPath: "/data/mongodb"

processManagement:
    pidFilePath: "/data/mongodb/pid"

net:
    port: 27017

security:
    keyFile: "/etc/ssl/mongodb.key"

replication:
    replSetName: general
```

Comment: Please go through the below link http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux-in-azure/

Comment: @Karthick thanks for the link. I have already tried it.

Comment: Does it worked or not?

Comment: The replica set works (as it does in my current setup with ubuntu) but I have the same issues. i.e. MMS and Python app are giving the same errors.

Comment: are the ports opened?

Comment: @EasterOfCode yes the ports are open. As I said in the question, I am able to connect to each replica set member from each VM and my own machine using the standard mongo command line client.

Comment: Unless you have modified the error messages, it appears as though you may have configured the hostname in MMS as a regex: `mdb-0[1-4].domain.com`. The MMS agent needs an actual hostname in order to connect to the replica set and discover the configuration (i.e. you should use `mdb-01.domain.com` or a valid DNS name from the point of view of the machine running the MMS agent).

Comment: Sorry, should have said, yes i did modify it to indicate that there was 4 machines.